# Google rejected my app with review, Please update your app to target API level 26

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have uploaded the `apk` to google play but unfortunately it is rejected

Review from Google:

> • Your app needs to be using runtime permissions for us to complete
>   the review. Please update your app to target API level 26 or above and
>   resubmit the declaration for

My app has `targetSdkVersion 28`

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" /> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

NOTE: for send_sms permission i have submitted the google compliance form.

gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 28
    //buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 20
        versionName "3.3.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "Xg"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/Classes', 'src/main/java/2']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3.jar')
    implementation(name: 'android-maps-utils-0.4', ext: 'aar')
    // implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

}
configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: updated please check

Comment: Are you using SEND_SMS permission in your app?

Comment: Yes, but my app comes under the given exceptions(please refer URL)https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en

Comment: have you implemented run time permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

instead you should use [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview).
check Google's policy changes [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html).

Comment: But i want to send SMS from client mobile.

Comment: @FirzanShaikh You have to implement the Sms Retriver OTP in order to do that.